# Raspi camera module not working in separate process

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to build a multiprocess app that will run on a Raspberry Pi. One of the processes is supposed to get a frame from the rpi camera and save it to disk for one of the other processes to use. However, there is something funky going on with how the python `multiprocessing.Process` class is handling the rpi camera module.

Basically, if I try to run the rpi camera module inside of a `Process`, it freezes up at the `for frame in self.camera.capture_continuous` line.

Here's some example code:

main.py

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import camera as c
import time, atexit, sh


def cleanUp():
    print("Killed the following processes:\n{}".format(
        sh.grep(sh.ps("aux", _piped=True), "python3")))
    sh.pkill("python3")


# Used to keep any of the processes from being orphaned
atexit.register(cleanUp)

proc = Process(target=c.run)
proc.start()

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("main")
```

camera.py

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import cv2

camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (1280, 720)
camera.framerate = 30
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(1280, 720))


def run():
    print("run function started")
    for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
        print("this never runs")
        cv2.imwrite('frame.jpg', frame.array)
        rawCapture.truncate(0)
```

Any insights?

Comment: If you believe the problem is running the RaspiCamera module inside a Process, please show the simplest code that tries to do that and doesn't work - no need to show a Flask app or any HTML. You should show the **Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example** see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Here's the updated, simplified version.

Comment: It's getting late here, so I'll take a look over the weekend. It does look simpler now, thank you. Did you try a quick print statement after camera initialisation to see if it initialised ok? And did you try running the module outside **multiprocessing**, i.e. stand-alone? And can you confirm no other programs are accessing the camera?

Comment: I've verified that the camera initialized, I ran the function outside of the `Process` and it worked. And from past experience, if the camera is being used by another resource, initializing the camera will fail with a 
 **picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: Camera component couldn't be enabled: Out of resources (other than memory)** which I'm not getting.

Comment: If it helps, I am working on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ with Raspian Stretch.

Comment: I am not sure the initialisation in `camera.py` gets run because your Process `target` is only `c.run()`

Comment: Just double checked it. If I place a print statement after the line that assigns `rawCapture` it runs prior to running the `run()` function. As far as I understand it, whenever you import something in python, it will run any code that is not inside a function or class.

Comment: Ah! Maybe that is exactly the problem! When you import it, it runs the initialisation in the original process, then starts a new process and there are now 2 processes accessing the camera which the docs explicitly say will not work!

Comment: Try moving the initialisation into the `run()` function.

Comment: That did it! If you submit it as a solution, I'll accept it.

Comment: Cool - glad we got you up and running. It's now very late here, so I'll write it up tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you have two distinct processes accessing the **PiCamera** module and that is explicitly forbidden in the FAQ at [Section 5.16](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/faq.html) in the documentation:

> The camera firmware is designed to be used by a single process at a time. Attempting to use the camera from multiple processes simultaneously will fail in a variety of ways (from simple errors to the process locking up).

I reduced your code to a minimum to show the issue, which is that the camera initialisation is performed when the `camera.py` module is imported within the first process but reading the images is performed in the spawned child process - hence two processes are accessing the camera.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from multiprocessing import Process
import camera as c
import time

proc = Process(target=c.run)
proc.start()

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("main")
```

And the `camera.py` module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

print('Running in process: {}'.format(os.getpid()))
print('camera = PiCamera()')
print('camera.resolution = (1280, 720)')
print('camera.framerate = 30')
print('rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(1280, 720))')


def run():
    print("run function started")
    print('Running in process: {}'.format(os.getpid()))
```

When you run it, you will see that two different process ids are reported:

**Sample Output**

```
Running in process: 51513
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (1280, 720)
camera.framerate = 30
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(1280, 720))
run function started
Running in process: 51514
main
main
main
```

One solution is to initialise the camera within the `run()` function.